# Google fonts not applying in IE9

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-webfonts

I am having an issue with customizing a WordPress template.

When I try to apply a Google Web font to a phone number in the header (as in dev [dot] beyondbbd [dot] com), Google fonts don't seem to be applied to the phone number (or all across the site for that matter) in IE9.

Any ideas about this? Is there an easy fix that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

-Nick

Comment: Good. But what about css code where you link a font? You have numerous css files and I see no reason to look for that small piece of code.

Comment: @FAngel This is at the top of the /style.css file


#phonenumber{
font-size: 1em;
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
bottom: 7px;
clear:none;
}

Comment: Sorry. I've found that that you are using prepared css file from google. But it is called "Open Sans" and not "Open Sans Condensed". Try to change `font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;` to `font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;`. I'm not sure if it will work, but you can try

Comment: I checked the phone # at the top of the screen and it's rendering for me on Chrome, Win 7x64. If you're behind a really stringent firewall sometimes the remotely-hosted fonts won't load. (I see this when I'm at work ... I work in healthcare.)

Comment: It shows in FF13, Win 7, as well.

Comment: @FAngel, I've tried switching the CSS as you mentioned. It didn't make a difference (thanks for the suggestion, though).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Isn't that bizzare? Any idea as to what is causing it for IE9 though?

Comment: Any chance you could give this question some up-votes so we can increase participation? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It renders in IE9 for me, Win7x64. It's probably a firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rearranging your css files so that the Google stylesheet comes before your own stylesheet which calls the fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have moved the Google Stylesheet (if this is the code you were referring to) to the top:

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,800italic,300italic,600italic,400,800,700,300,600|Open+Sans+Condensed:700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Comment: It doesn't appear to have worked. IE9 is still showing the font embedding not working. Is it possible that another embedded font is conflicting? I still see a flash upon load with that font. I can't figure out what other font might be conflicting though.

Comment: I've just checked it on IE9 on adobe browser labs and it seems to be displaying that font fine in IE9 on there as far as I can see. I see the same font that I see on Safari on my Macbook.

Comment: Is there any reason why browserlab would show it working (which I've also seen) but my IE9 wouldn't?

Comment: Not sure, there's always that old favourite have you tried clearing your cache? Does the font show up okay for you in IE9 on the Google Fonts page? http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Open+Sans+Condensed

Comment: I've cleared all my browsing data, still seeing it. I'm thinking about just using an ie-specific style-sheet...